# WPF Styling Not Working as Expected

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I have the following style applied to a Button (enabled by default):

```
<Style x:Key="DisableFoxProCancelButton" 
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FoxProTableIsDirty}" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This works to disable the button when FoxProTableIsDirty is False.

I originally had this wired up as follows (disabled by default):

```
<Style x:Key="DisableFoxProCancelButton" 
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FoxProTableIsDirty}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But this second way did not work to disable the button when FoxProTableIsDirty is False.

The second style seemed to make more sense when I was writing the style as by default the button should be disabled until a change is made to the associated table and the changes need to be saved.

Can someone explain why the second one would not work as expected?

**EDIT**

Here is the code for the button using this style:

```
<Button Name="CancelFoxproChanges"
            Content="Cancel"
            Style="{StaticResource DisableFoxProCancelButton}"
            DockPanel.Dock="Right"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}"
                                 MethodName="FoxProCancelButtonClicked" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: The WPF looks right at first glance.  So perhaps the problem is with the implementation of the FoxProTableIsDirty property itself, rather than with the WPF.  Is the FoxProTableIsDirty a dependency property, or does it fire INotifyPropertyChanged events?  I assume it is a Boolean not a string.

Comment: FoxProTableIsDirty is a Boolean property (set to False at startup) on the VM and it does correctly fire the INotifyPropertyChanged event.

Comment: I found that the issue came from the BasedOn style.  Apparently MultiDataTriggers are not overriden but cumulative and the BasedOn style had a MultiDataTrigger that was setting the button to enabled.

Answer (score 1):

check if there is `IsEnabled` set in the `Button` element.

remove if it is set as triggers can not override local or inline values.

<Button Style="{StaticResource DisableFoxProCancelButton}" <strike>IsEnabled="False"</strike> />

---

in other way you can directly bind FoxProTableIsDirty to Button's IsEnabled, eg

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding FoxProTableIsDirty}" />
```

or via style setters

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding FoxProTableIsDirty}" />
```

so as long as `FoxProTableIsDirty` is being resolved and notifying changes, this will enable/disable the button as desired

Comment: IsEnabled is NOT being overridden in the Button tag (see edit).  I agree that moving this as suggested is better but would like to understand why it doesn't work as I originally set it up.

Comment: @BrianKE, your code looks correct. to analyze further is it possible for you to post a working sample of your app which can reproduce the issue you are facing?